# How can I bind a field to a user control

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my user control I have this property:

```
    public static DependencyProperty FooListProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        "FooList", typeof(List<Problem>), typeof(ProblemView));

    public List<Problem> FooList
    {
        get
        {
            return (List<Problem>)GetValue(FooListProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(FooListProperty, value);
        }
    }

    protected override void OnPropertyChanged(DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnPropertyChanged(e);

        if (e.Property == FooListProperty)
        {
            // Do something
        }
    }
```

And since another window, I´m trying to set a value for the last user control:

```
    <local:ProblemView HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center" FooList="{Binding list}" />
```

And that window in load contains:

```
    public List<Problem> list;

    private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Some processes and it sets to list field
        list = a;
    }
```

But in XAML code, binding it isn't working. Don't pass the data. What am I wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't bind to a Field in WPF, you'll have to change `list` to a property instead.

You call the Dependency Property `FooList` in your `UserControl` and `ResultList` in Xaml but I'm guessing that's a typo in the question.

You should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` in the `Window` to let the Bindings know that the value has been updated.

I'm not sure if you have the correct `DataContext` set in the Xaml `ProblemView`, if you're unsure you can name the `Window` and use `ElementName` in the binding

```
<Window Name="window"
        ...>
    <!--...-->
    <local:ProblemView HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                       VerticalAlignment="Center"
                       ResultList="{Binding ElementName=window,
                                            Path=List}" />
    <!--...-->
</Window>
```

*Sample code behind*

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    //...

    private List<Problem> m_list;
    public List<Problem> List
    {
        get { return m_list; }
        set
        {
            m_list = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("List");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged Members

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    private void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }

    #endregion
}
```

Comment: Thanks a million Meleak, it's working. In fact, this is same question that I asked you. I really appreaciate your help.